# Magento 2 : How to get data from headers?

Tags: magento2, header

I am passing "id" in headers & trying to get its value in custom script.

using below code

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$response = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface');
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
print_r($request->getPost()); exit;
```

But i am not getting any data..

any thoughts what i am missing ?

Comment: I have tried to send data from post man & get data in script but its empty.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,

    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    
    public function getRequestTest() 
    {
        $requestParams = $this->request->getParams();
        //get values of current limit. If not the param value then it will set to 12
        $pageSize = ($this->request->getParam('pageSize'));
        $page = ($this->request->getParam('currentPage'));
    }
```

Using object manager

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$response = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface');
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');  
print_r($request->getParams());
```

get header

```
echo $request->getHeader('DK_ID');
```

or

```
$httpRequestObject = new \Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$httpRequestObject->getHeader('DK_ID');
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, i have tried this code in script but i get empty array.

Please have a look at this request https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/8409734?key=cef5919d8ddefc03a044c9b55206919b

Comment: I have updated code & check, i receive blank response.
Is their any way i can check either then postman ?

Comment: use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface

Comment: $request->getHeader('DK_ID'); like this

Comment: I mean using any other tool instead of postman ?

Comment: i think no.....

Comment: +1 for efforts answering.
This seems working but not for custom header.